# ngrx vs redux - stateless components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, redux

I'm working with ngrx/angular 8 for the first time and am trying to understand if the angular paradigm of using an observable to bind a state value to the `this` context still allows a component to be presentational/stateless.

does doing the following with angular/ngrx, still allow a component (in this case (`<settings-component></settings-component>`) to be "Presentational/Stateless"?

````
//settings-component.js
this.settings$ = this.store.select(selectSettings)
//template for component
<div>{this.settings$}</div>```

//and then somewhere else in the app (notice no props):

<settings-component></settings-component>
````

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. The reason is simple: it depends on something in the external, "global" state that is not passed in.

My understanding of presentational/stateless Angular components is that they can be used in virtually any Angular app without needing to configure specific services or other dependencies at the module level. Everything they need gets passed in via input props and passed out via output props.

Comment: hmm so a follow on question... if a component interacts with ngrx store directly, that makes it stateful by nature correct? I don't think there is any equivalent of `mapStateToProps` in ngrx, which would allow stateless interaction with a store...

https://stackoverflow.com/q/64068491/4178793