# ngrx stateless components + interacting with store

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

is it possible to write stateless components that interact with ngrxs store?

almost all the examples i've seen do not use @Input to provide state to components, but instead use the `this` context inside a component to retrieve state with a selector, which by definition makes the component stateful.

i don't believe there is any equivalent of mapStateToProps in ngrx, which would allow stateless interaction with a store..

Comment: I think if you are using state from the store then your component cannot be stateless. So when you say - "allow stateless interaction with a store" - It is a contradiction.It also depends on what is the meaning of "interaction"? i.e. only dispatch action and no consumption of the state from the store?

Comment: Usually to do this in an Angular way is to have a wrapper component that talks to the store and gets the data and then the data is pushed down to the child components using `@Input()` properties.

Comment: @AliF50 but this doesn’t solve the issue of prop drilling... so then what’s the point of redux?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example.

Say you have an aspect in the application that is responsible for displaying the products for sale.

products.component.ts (stateful component)

```
product$ = this.store.select(getProducts);
selectedProduct: IProduct;
constructor(private store: Store<ProductsState>) { }

setSelectedProduct(product: IProduct) {
  this.selectedProduct = product;
}
```

products.component.html

```
<product-details *ngFor="let product of products$ | async"
   [product]="product"
   (productSelected)="setSelectedProduct($event)"
></product-details>
<div class="selected-product" *ngIf="selectedProduct">
  <selected-product
    [product]="selectedProduct"
  ></selected-product>
</div>
```

product-details.component.ts (stateless, responsible for listening to click on product and emitting which item got clicked on)

```
@Input() product: IProduct;
@Output() productSelected = new EventEmitter<IProduct>();

onProductSelect() {
  this.productSelected.emit(this.product);
}
```

product-details.component.html

```
<div (click)="onProductSelect()">
  <div>{{ product.id }}</div>
  <div>{{ product.name }}</div>
</div>
```

selected-product.component.ts (responsible for showing the clicked on product at the bottom)

```
@Input() product: IProduct;
```

selected-product.component.html

```
<img src="product.img" alt="product image" />
<div class="rating">{{product.rating}}</div>
<div *ngFor="let comment of product.reviewComments"> {{ comment }}</div>
```

So the idea is to make a feature slice related to your application and one component would be the stateful component (knows how to talk to the store) which is products.component.ts. Every other view gets the data inputted to it.

This doesn't solve the issue of prop drilling but it will make unit testing the components that have @Input() and @Output() (stateless components) easy.

I use this approach in React as well where I have one stateful component (with mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps) and then I pass the properties down as props making unit tests easier.

I wouldn't consider child components with `mapStateToProps` in React stateless either because they still have to know how to read from the store and writing unit tests for this will be difficult as well because you would have to mock the store or give the store when doing unit tests.

Another advantage of this prop drilling is that one component is responsible for reading from the store and if the structure of the store changes, the code change has to be done in one component and the properties will be flowing down just like before. But with the approach of each child component having `mapStateToProps`, the change of the structure of the store would have be done in each place that has `mapStateToProps`.

If you want to have `this.store.select()` in multiple places, that's fine as well but that's equivalent to `mapStateToProps` in multiple places. Basically, if you can do prop drilling as outlined, unit testing and refactoring would be easier.